# combining statements with jquery, and using media queries for a back to top button

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, media-queries, scrolltop

I am always confused with writing statements in jQuery. I'm trying to get this back-top button to only appear on larger screen widths and hide on mobile.

How do I combine statements or change up my code properly to get it to work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Back to Top
    $("#back-top").hide(); // hide #back-top first

    // fade in after 500px down
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
          if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500 && screen.width >= 641) {
            $('#back-top').fadeIn();
          } else {
            $('#back-top').fadeOut();
          }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#back-top').click(function () {
          $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0 }, 800); // 0px from top, 800 duration
          return false;
        });
    });

    if (screen.width < 641) {
        $("#back-top").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Css:

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
  #back-top{ 
     display: none!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)